# Can't resolve all parameters for Storage: (?) - Angular JWT App Module

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to configure Angular2-Jwt for Ionic 2. Before I updated Ionic the following code worked. Now it doesn't. I know there was changes to Ionic Storage wihch is causing the issue but I don't understand how I can convert the following code:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { ElasticModule } from 'angular2-elastic';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { NumberBoard } from '../components/number-board/number-board';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { CloudSettings, CloudModule } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
import { IonicStorageModule, Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

let storage: Storage = new Storage();

export function getAuthHttp(http) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    headerName: 'token',
    noTokenScheme: true,
    globalHeaders: [{'Accept': 'application/json'}],
    tokenGetter: (() => storage.get('token'))
  }), http);
};

const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': 'c3890396'
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    NumberBoard
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    {provide: AuthHttp, useFactory: getAuthHttp, deps: [Http]},
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/crop": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.11.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "angular2-elastic": "^0.13.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.0.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "Rediyal-Business: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: can you show your `package.json` file?

Comment: Done @Sampath :)

Comment: are you using `Ionic 3 beta`?

Comment: Nope, Ionic 2.2.2

Comment: Then why `Angular 4` here `"@angular/core": "4.0.0",` ? how it happned?

Comment: I'm not sure, all I did was start a fresh Ionic app using 'ionic start MyAppName sidemenu --v2 --ts'

Comment: 'ionic -v' shows 2.2.2

Comment: Can't be.just create a new project again on a fresh folder and share the `package.json` with us?

Comment: Oh ..Wait a min..

Comment: It's still showing @angular/core 4.0.0

Comment: Yes,you're right.can you run `ionic serve`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like:

```
let storage: Storage = new Storage();
```

does not work in version 2.0.0 onwards.
Check [ionic storage code](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-storage/blob/master/src/storage.ts#L112).
Its constructor takes a parameter.

> ```
> constructor(config: StorageConfig)
> ```

You should be able to use it by injecting into a constructor like a provider though.

```
 constructor(private storage: Storage)
```

Dependency Injection set [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-storage/blob/master/src/index.ts#L15).

> ```
> { provide: Storage, useFactory: provideStorage, deps: [StorageConfigToken]},
> ```

Also try

```
let storage: Storage = new Storage(null);
```